# Cannot delimit multi column values using unnest function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a multi-values column as seen below:

[image]

I am using PostgreSQL to count the number of occurrence of each letter. I want to end up with a table of two columns. The first column should show the letter and the second should show the count.

Here's what I have attempted so far:

```
SELECT  unnest(string_to_array(letters, ' ')) as LETTERS,COUNT(LETTERS) FROM tableName

GROUP BY LETTERS;
```

I get the following result: 
[image]

Somehow, the letters are repeating themselves. Ideally, I want to see this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Oh, after I posted my answer I realized your mistake, you shouldn't use `letters` as an alias for your new unnested column, or use `group by 1` instead of `group by letters`! That's all :)
`SELECT
    unnest(string_to_array(letters, ' ')) as LETTER,
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    tableName
GROUP BY
    LETTER;`

Answer (score 1):

try using `regexp_split_to_array` instead of `string_to_array`

```
select
    unnest(regexp_split_to_array(trim(letters), '\s+')) as letter,
    count(*) as letter_count
from
    <your_table_name>
group by
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single space character as the delimiter. If you want to get every character in the string, pass `null` as the delimiter for `string_to_array`:

Set returning functions like `unnest()` should also be used in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT l.letter,
       count(*) as letters
FROM tableName, 
     unnest(string_to_array(letters, null)) as l(letter)
GROUP BY letter;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/CZKVP53369

Comment: I am getting a syntax error near "letters" which is inside the unnest function.

Comment: @bangbang: then - contrary to the code in your question - you do not have a column name `letters` in your table